# Unable to sync Entities with database in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I am starting to explore Symfony and after create the schema by importing [this sql](http://www.amimusa.org/amimusa.sql) script and create the entities following these commands:

```
Importing mapping information by generating the metadata files:

    $ php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeBlogBundle xml

Build related entity classes:
    -> Generates entity classes with annotation mappings
    $ php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src
    $ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeBlogBundle
```

The command:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

fails with the following error:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]                                                                              
  An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE writtings CHANGE id id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL':                
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of './amimusa/#sql-425_5e' to './amimusa/writtings' (errno: 150)                                                                                                 
  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]                                                                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of './amimusa/#sql-425_5e' to './amimusa/writtings' (errno: 150)  
  [PDOException]                                                                                                         
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of './amimusa/#sql-425_5e' to './amimusa/writtings' (errno: 150)
```

The dump file generated is:

```
ALTER TABLE writtings CHANGE id id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE writtings ADD CONSTRAINT FK_F9A6AFF48726D6E4 FOREIGN KEY (publication_type) REFERENCES publications_type (id);
ALTER TABLE musas CHANGE id id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE publications DROP FOREIGN KEY contributor_FK;
ALTER TABLE publications DROP FOREIGN KEY state_FK;
ALTER TABLE publications DROP FOREIGN KEY writting_FK;
ALTER TABLE publications CHANGE id id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, CHANGE id_contributor id_contributor INT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE id_state id_state INT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE id_writting id_writting INT DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE publications ADD CONSTRAINT FK_32783AF440C1075C FOREIGN KEY (id_writting) REFERENCES writtings (id);
ALTER TABLE publications ADD CONSTRAINT FK_32783AF44D1693CB FOREIGN KEY (id_state) REFERENCES states (id);
ALTER TABLE publications ADD CONSTRAINT FK_32783AF4C27D5A64 FOREIGN KEY (id_contributor) REFERENCES contributors (id);
ALTER TABLE publications_musas DROP FOREIGN KEY musa_FK;
ALTER TABLE publications_musas DROP FOREIGN KEY publication_FK;
ALTER TABLE publications_musas DROP FOREIGN KEY musa_FK;
ALTER TABLE publications_musas CHANGE id_publication id_publication INT NOT NULL, CHANGE id_musa id_musa INT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE publications_musas ADD CONSTRAINT FK_7EF2161FB72EAA8E FOREIGN KEY (id_publication) REFERENCES publications (id);
ALTER TABLE publications_musas ADD CONSTRAINT FK_7EF2161FFB53D80 FOREIGN KEY (id_musa) REFERENCES musas (id);
DROP INDEX musa_fk ON publications_musas;
CREATE INDEX IDX_7EF2161FFB53D80 ON publications_musas (id_musa);
ALTER TABLE publications_musas ADD CONSTRAINT musa_FK FOREIGN KEY (id_musa) REFERENCES musas (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE contributors CHANGE id id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE states CHANGE id id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL;
```

Anybody could help me to understand why the update fails?
Also I can't figure out why these operations are required since everything has been created from scratch.

Comment: The reverse engineering stuff is not perfect.  Doctrine likes to have things defined it's own way.  I'd suggest dropping the database then use doctrine:schema:create to rebuild it the way doctrine wants it to be.

Comment: yep, that worked! thanks

Answer (score 0):

As [Cerad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1146363/cerad) commented:

> The reverse engineering stuff is not perfect. Doctrine likes to have
>   things defined it's own way. I'd suggest dropping the database then
>   use doctrine:schema:create to rebuild it the way doctrine wants it to
>   be.

```
$ php app/console doctrine:schema:drop --force
$ php app/console doctrine:schema:create
```

Has fixed the issue.